# Access forbidden during the installation of the Lizmap server on Windows

Tags: windows, php, apache, lizmap

How can I successfully install Lizmap? I have exhausted all the means of research without success. In fact, for more than a week I have tried to install lizmap on Windows. At the step of the Apache configuration I receive a forbidden message. I've tried to test the connection, and I resumed several times always the same,

What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Would run each test listed here  https://github.com/NaturalGIS/qgis_server_and_lizmap_on_windows

Comment: If you just want to test Lizmap on Windows, it is easier to use : https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/tree/master/tests#with-windows. If you want Lizmap for production and know a bit of Docker you can use : https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-docker-compose

Comment: Note for Docker on Windows `Commercial use of Docker Desktop in larger enterprises (more than 250 employees OR more than $10 million USD in annual revenue) now requires a paid subscription.`  If that's an issue you can use WSL

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a permission problem. Normally LIZMAP runs fine under WINDOWS.

I would recommend running the Apache service under a dedicated user. To do this, you must enter the appropriate "Log on" user for the Apache service, who also has the "Log on as a Service" rights.

After that the write permissions for this user have to be set for some directories. The corresponding directories can be found in the file `./lizmap/install/set_rights.sh`:

```
./lizmap/var/config
./lizmap/var/db
./lizmap/var/log
./lizmap/var/mails
./lizmap/var/uploads
./lizmap/var/lizmap-theme-config
./temp/lizmap
./lizmap/www/cache
./lizmap/www/document
./lizmap/www/live
```